# How to set up a post commit hook that run "xterm -e unison &" after I commit?

Tags: linux, svn, csv, git-svn

How to set up a post commit hook in svn that run "xterm -e unison &" after I commit?

cheers

daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your experience level, so here's a [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) to the Subversion book on how to implement hook scripts on the Subversion repository.

Basically, your going to want to use the post-commit.tmpl hook file, make a copy of it named `post-commit` and modify it to fit your needs.  Make sure you have the appropriate permissions and ownership set right or your access method to the repository (Apache HTTD, svnserver, file) may cause the hook script to not be invoked.

You should be able to add the command you listed above to the hook script.  If the hook script has problems executing that line, try using fully qualified paths to the executable and any arguments that should have it.

As side question, what are you hoping to accomplish with `xterm -e unison &` anyway?

Comment: thank you for your answer =) this command is supposed to open a new console window and execute unison so that the user can log in with his credentials and the synch get started.